# mocking the session argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to write a unit test for the above method in a different file say `test.py`. I am unable to mock the session.

```
# app.py
import requests

def get_json_data(url, session):
    response = session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()
```

I have come with the following test. It fails

```
class TestDoSessionGet(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('requests.session')
    def test_should_mock_session_get(self, mocker):

        data = """{
                        "userId": 1,
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "delectus aut autem",
                        "completed": false
                    }"""
        j_data = json.loads(data)

        #print(j_data)
        mocker.return_value = Mock(ok=True)
        mocker.return_value.json.return_value = j_data

        response = get_json_data('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', requests.Session())
        print(response)
        self.assertTrue(mocker.called)
        self.assertEqual(response, j_data)
```

Comment: A unit test for the above method should pass a mock session object to the method to test its behaviour. You can use: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html more examples here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

Comment: You don't need to mock the session; you just need to pass an appropriate session (or session-like object) to the function when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the `requests` module. You can create a mocked `session` for testing `get_json_data` function.

E.g.

`app.py`:

```py
def get_json_data(url, session):
    response = session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()
```

`test_app.py`:

```py
import unittest
import json
from app import get_json_data
from unittest.mock import Mock


class TestDoSessionGet(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_should_mock_session_get(self):
        data = {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "title": "delectus aut autem",
            "completed": False
        }
        mock_session = Mock()
        mock_response = Mock()
        mock_session.get.return_value = mock_response
        mock_response.json.return_value = data

        response = get_json_data('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', mock_session)

        mock_session.get.assert_called_once_with('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        mock_response.raise_for_status.assert_called_once()
        mock_response.json.assert_called_once()
        self.assertEqual(response, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/60084306/app.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/60084306/test_app.py      18      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                       22      0   100%
```